# AngularJS: How do I share data accross all pages and controller of my SPA?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, controllers, data-sharing

What is the best way to share some data across all controllers and scopes of my Single page application ?

Let say i have a small set of data I want to be able to access everywhere, and I don't want to query the database every time I need it.

Comment: Use `RootScope` and you can access any data in RootScope in any of the controllers scope

Comment: @Xsmael : Utilize $rootScope , which is a globle variable in Angular js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shared data services seems to be the best aproach for your case. There is `$rootScope` as a global scope, but, `$rootScope` shoudn't be used for such thing due to performance issues. `$rootscope` is part of angular digest cycle, so when you add something to it, you are also adding something more to be checked. Therefore, it's not recommended to use unless it's extremely necessary.

For example, for simple services:

```
app.service('SharedDataService', function () {
     var Data = {
        field1: 'qweqwe',
        field2: '12312'
    };

    return Data;
});
```

For complex services with async operations:

```
app.service('SharedDataService', function () {
    var self = this; 
    this.getData = function () {
        if(self.cachedData){
            return $q.resolve(self.cachedData);
        }

        return $http.get('my-data-url').then(function (response) {
            self.cachedData = response.data;
            return self.cachedData;
        });
    };
});
```

And the controller:

```
app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, SharedDataService) {
    SharedDataService.getData().then(function (data) {
        $scope.data = data;
    });
});
```

Comment: uh, excuse me or this dumb question, but shall I use the same name "SharedDataService" as you mentioned? am asking that due to the way you explained

Comment: No problem @Xsmael you can name it whateverDataService you want but be sure to keep consistent names according to the service responsability. Also, there is a style guide for angularjs originally written by Jon Papa and maintained by him and the comunity that may help you. It have nice consideration about naming components and stuff, check this out

Comment: thanks! when is the code of the service executed? is it only when we access a controller where it has been injected or from the time the app is loaded ?

Comment: The function sent to the `.service('name', fnConstructor)` is a constructor, and both service and factory are singletons, this constructor is executed `once` when the service is called first time, which is when it is first injected.

Comment: yea thanks alot, but one problem i've just noticed is that when i start from home page and then navigate to others pages it's fine, but when i refresh or load from an arbitrary page, the view comes before the data gets loaded, hence it displays empty view... i guess that's another problem

Comment: No, it's not! That's why exists promises like shown in my second example, you can wait for async operations so then you set the value on the scope.

Comment: oh ok, but i'm using `$resource` not `$http` how do i get a promise with that; and i'm a bit confused with the return statement inside the callback function when is that return going to be executed?

Comment: It's the same, any of $resources's method will return an object that has a promise. For example supose that `Data` is a `$resource` of something, then, you can return the promise like `return Data.get().$promise.then(function (data) { console.log(data); });`

Comment: Alright! thanks a lot! you helped me :) thanks for your patience! God bless you!

Comment: @Xsmael You're wellcome :)

Answer (score 3):

The data to be stored in $rootscope variable

(or)

data to be stored in services

Answer (score 2):

Best to use service say `commonService` and after getting data from database store on a variable inside the service like this

```
this.dbDataSearch = function(parameters){
  // Search record from database
  this.resultData = data;
}
```

In Controller 1:

```
$scope.data = commonService.resultData;
```

In Controller 2:

```
$scope.data = commonService.resultData;
```

In Controller n:

```
$scope.data = commonService.resultData;
```

Comment: i like this approach but one question: when resultData gets updated, will it also get updated in  other controllers using it ? and you didnt show where you declare the service

Comment: Yes, that's the beauty of Angularjs

Comment: but when is the code of the service executed? is it only when we access a controller where it has been injected or from the time the app is loaded ?

Comment: if data is null call the method to get data from database, you can use a function, of you can check in every where you are using, it's up to you.
Better to use a  function to check and return conditionally.

Comment: so otherwise the code in the service will be executed many times, wherever it is injected am i right ?

Answer (score 1):

In angularJS you can perform this operation in different ways. either you can use $rootscope or you can broadcast data or you can use services or factories.

But the bet preferred way is to use services. First thing is it's easy. You can use the same service on every controller to access the data.

If you want to know more about angularjs services please check below link.

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-service-factory-tutorial/