# AnguarJS: using 'this' pointer or return statement

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

Which is the right way to declare a service ?

```
.service('myService', function(myFactory) {
    myFactory.LoadData("...",function(newData){
       this.data= newData;
    });
}
```

or

```
.service('myService', function() {
     var data= {};
     myFactory.LoadData("...",function(newData){
       data= newData;
       return data ;
    });

}
```

I don't want to make http calls everytime I use it but only once, and then access the data whenever I want.

I've tried the first example but i'm getting 'undefined' value when I try to use it in my controller.

**EDIT:**

ok here is my code:

the service :

```
.service('ClassService', function(ClassFactory) {                 

                ClassFactory.query(function(rawClasses){
                   this.classes= [];
                    rawClasses.forEach(function(classe) {
                        var classeRow={};
                        classeRow.grade=classe.grade;

                        classe.branch.forEach(function(branch) {
                            classeRow._id=branch._id;
                            classeRow.branch= branch.name;
                            classeRow.fees= branch.fees;

                            branch.sub_class.forEach(function(subClass) {
                                classeRow.label=subClass.label;
                                classeRow.name= _getGradeName_(classeRow.grade)+(classeRow.branch || '')+ (subClass.label || '');
                                console.info('ClasseService hihihi!');
                                this.classes.push(_byValue_(classeRow));  
                                     console.log( this.classes);    

                            }, this);
                        }, this);                
                    }, this);
                });    
        })
```

and the controller:

```
.controller('StudentController', function(StudentFactory, ClassService, $scope, $stateParams) {
    //...
    $scope.classes= ClassService.classes;
    //but here console.log($scope.classes) gives  'undefined'
    //...
});
```

Comment: My first thought is there is a promise on that $http.get.

Comment: Factories instantiate by calling the function and using the return value. Services instantiate by using the 'new' operator on the function so they create a new object which you can reference as `this`.
So short answer is use either but the second one needs to use `factory` not `service`.
However, `$http.get()` returns a promise so you need to use `.then()` on it to wait for the value to arrive.

Comment: Checkout the second example of this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/40087580/4488121

Comment: sorry i didn't stated my problem correctly, i've edited it now!

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro that Woked, for me! writing `var self= this` and using `self `all the way down instead of `this`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The query in your service is running asynchronously so you need to use a promise to wait for the value to become available.

If you make `ClassFactory.query()` return a promise instead of using a callback it will all become much simpler. Use `thePromise.then()` in `ClassService` to handle the completion, but that also returns a promise which you should expose to the controller. Then in the controller use another `.then()` to know when the data is available.

So assuming you've updated `ClassFactory.query()` to return a promise:

```
.service('ClassService', function(ClassFactory) {                 

     var promise =ClassFactory.query();
     this.dataLoaded = promise.then(... the code to convert rawClasses to this.classes goes here...);
})
```

and:

```
.controller('StudentController', function(StudentFactory, ClassService, $scope, $stateParams) {
    //...
    ClassService.dataLoaded.then(function () {
        $scope.classes= ClassService.classes;
    });
});
```

Comment: okay, i can try that, but normally my code should work, because i did several 'console.log' and ti shows that once the home page is loaded the `ClassService ` gets all the data and process it nicely, and then when i move to the page where the `StudentController` is defined, it was supposed to used that data from the service but shows `undefined` even though the data is available. i don't understand why

Comment: You should always use a promise, so I think this answer is on to something.

Comment: @Xsmael the that your query completes asynchronously so the data is not available until after your controller has failed to access it. However the scoping with `this` was also an issue.